# Communicate your pending payment/per hour charges to someone

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english

I am tutoring some students on a subject. Recently a friend of them also wanted to take session with me. Now he has scheduled a second session. As it was a reference from someone so we didn't discuss pricing n all. But now I need to discuss it. I am not sure how to make it sound polite.

Could I message him simply - **I charge $xyz/hr** ? or there is a better way to communicate this ?

Comment: Are you asking if a message saying nothing but "I charge $xyz/hr" is polite? Or are you asking if it is correct to say that within a message that also says other things?

Comment: Just the message saying `I charge $x/hr`. I get  a feeling it's better to sandwich it between words to make it look better. Like I could add. We will discuss this today etc.. and in between I could add a line like that

Comment: You might send him a message saying: **Hello X, you are welcome to attend another session.  I charge $x an hour, payable at the start of each session. Will you kindly confirm that this is acceptable to you.**